# Open Telegram InlineQuery Search instantly using @mentions

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am developing a telegram bot which will be able to answer **inline queries** in order to provide the user with search results. I chose inline queries, because I like that it's a live search.

I don't want the user to always type `@nameOfBot` in order to start a live search. Do you know if there is a shorter way? Is there a possibility to preset the message input field with a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to make an inline search without typing the bot username, but you can use `switch_inline_query` in [InlineKeyboardButton](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inlinekeyboardbutton) to add a inline button that will auto type the bot username (and, optionally, the query you like) in the input text.